# How to display console output of Eclipse？

Tags: android, console

I use Java to input XML content. Currently it just displays the last part of the output, and the first part can not be seen.

How can I display to the console all output of Eclipse? Where can I set this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately eclipse cannot display all your out(even logcat cannot do that). To get all your put displayed you need to implement a logger which can write and save all your output somewhere.

look at this tutorials to see how to do it
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm